# Symfony 2.7 how to access to _fragment?

Tags: symfony, esi

After hours of search, i ask this question here because i think that there is no answers was found for this issue.

The problem is very simple: Trying to access to _fragment outside twig that works fine whith render_esi function in twig.

I disabled the trusted proxy entry in config.yml:

```
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: false
fragments:        
    path: /_fragment
    enabled: true
```

And in security.yml, i put :

```
anonymous:    true
```

When i try to access any fragment via web browser, i got and AccessDenied Exception with message in the profiler saying: "You are not logged in".

What is the problem of this ? why profiler is saying that i'm not logged in ?

Here is the last error log:

```
at FragmentListener ->validateRequest (object(Request))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/FragmentListener.php at line 65
```

Thank you